# How to run ASP.NET project connecting Visual Studio with github

Tags: c#, asp.net, github

I have a github repository with an ASP.NET project.

I've connected my Visual Studio 2019 with Github (And cloned the repository).

When I try to run the webpage appears this error:

Configuration error Description: Error during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Review the following specific error details and modify the configuration file accordingly.

Analyzer error message: The provider type CodeDom "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version = 1.0.7.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e364e364e364e364e364e

Source Code Error:

````
Línea 23:         <compilers>
Línea 24:             <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
Línea 25:                 type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
Línea 26:                 warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>```
````

Comment: please provide localization for your error in English, or switch to other stackoverflow website, https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: sorry, it's edited now

Comment: don't see any relation to github

Comment: @ManuelRodriguez updated solution, let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to need to Install `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` Nuget Package

*Right Click your Project*

```
 Manage Nuget Packages > Browse > Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform > Install
```